# Weird anchors in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, frameworks, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to use Twitter Bootstrap's (2.0) Dropdown menu.

But somewhy it adds additional empty `a` elements making it looke very weird:

[image: Dropdown weird gray line]

See the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rCFGY/).

The questions:

1. Why is it happening (what am I doing wrong)?
2. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly closing your "Contacts" menu item so the markup is being displayed as if the dropdown menu was part of your main link. Just add a closing `</a>` tag at the end of the `.caret` div and it works:

```
<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
  <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
      Contacts
        <b class='caret'></b></a> /* here */
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href="/x">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/x">Networks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rCFGY/1/

Comment: Spot on! Thanks. I start to understand why people don't like HAML :)

Comment: Andres, the ending of anchor the third from the end should be remove as you have added at the _here_ position.

Comment: @Jasonw i don't understand your question, you mean its at the wrong place?

Comment: </a>
  </li>
</ul>
the </a> seem additional since you have added </a> before </b>

Comment: @Jasonw Not additional since the closing `</b>` bold tag only closes the bold caret element, we still have to close the link. The submenu is a child of the `li` element and not part of the link itself.

Comment: @Jasonw here is the proper documentation for the bootstrap nav tabs with the usage of the markup in place, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs